# Data organisation: How to transform time series to individual data

Tags: dataframe, organization, raw-data

I have a dataset of individuals at different time steps but I only have data entries when a change happens. So I have e.g. the takeover date of a territory but I want to know for each individual whether they were present or absent at a given time step.

```
  ID<-c("A","B","C","D","E")
    Takeover<-c(0,5,5,8,12)
    data<-data.frame(ID,Takeover)
```

So in this simplified data A was there in timesteps 1:4 and at timestep 5 B & C took over and stayed until timestep 8....

I then want to get an individual dataset that looks something like this

[image]

How do I organise my data?

However, I don't know how to this...

Comment: Noise reduction; layout.